# Laravel route method problems

Tags: php, html, laravel

## Basic Information

I' developing a simple Web Application using Laravel6.0.

And I made image post form at my create2.blade.php (blade file) file.

But my form seems to be having a routing Problem.

## Problem

[image: The error message that annoying me.]

## My Codes

### routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('login');

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'StoriesController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'StoriesController@index');

    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@store');
    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@upload');
    Route::get('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
});

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth','name'=>'profile'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
    Route::get('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@store');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@upload');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

### app/Http/Controllers/StoriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Story;
use Auth;
use App\Posts;
use App\History;
use App\Attachment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  public function index(Request $request)
      {
        $images = Attachment::all();

        return view('stories.index2', compact('images'));
      }

  public function add()
    {
      return view('stories.create2');
    }


  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $d = new \DateTime();
    $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
    $dir = $d->format('Y/m');
    $path = sprintf('public/images/%s', $dir);


    $data = $request->except('_token');

    foreach ($data['images'] as $k => $v) {

      $filename = '';


      $attachments = Attachment::take(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

      foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        $filename = $attachment->id + 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }
      unset($attachment);

      if ($filename == false) {
        $filename = 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }

      $v->storeAs($path, $filename);

      $attachment_data = [
        'path' => sprintf('images/%s/', $dir),
        'name' => $filename
      ];

      $a = new Attachment();
      $a->fill($attachment_data)->save();
    }

    unset($k, $v);

    return redirect('/');
  }


  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => [
          'required',
          'file',
          'image',
          'mimes:jpeg,png',
        ]
      ]);

      if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
        $path = $request->file->store('public');
        return view('stories.index2')->with('filename', basename($path));
      } else {
        return redirect('/')
          ->back()
          ->withInput()
          ->withErrors();
      }
    }
}
```

### resources/views/stories/create2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','StoryCreate')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('/css/main22.css' )}}" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="poststory">
    <h1>Post Story</h1>
</div>
@if ($errors->any())
<ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form">
        <label for="photo" class="file">Choose Image or Video</label>
        <div class="post">
            <input type="file" class="here" name="images[]">

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="btn postbtn">
            <input type="submit" value="post" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@endsection
```

### resources/views/stories/index2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','mainpage')

@section('content')
<div class="profile">

    <div class="profileimg">
        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" style="height: 210px; width: 210px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="name">
        @guest
        <a class="nav-link2" href="{{ route('register')}}">{{ __('Create Accout!')}}</a>
        @else
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link2" href="#" role="button">
            {{Auth::user()->name}}<span class="caret"></span></a>



        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
    @endguest


    <div class="aboutme">
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
    </div>

</div>

<div class="new">

    <div class="newtitle">
        <h1>New</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">

        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" class="images" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
        <div class="more">
            more...
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="stories">

    <div class="titlestories">
        <h1>Stories</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">

        <div class="titleclose">
            <h2>#CloseFriends</h2>
        </div>

        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" class="images" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach

        <div class="titlefollow">
            <h2>#Follows</h2>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

{{ csrf_field() }}
@endsection
```

## What I tried.

I cleared the caches using this command,

```
$php artisan route: clear
```

and I' made a new cache using

```
$composer dump-autoload
$php artisan clear-compiled
$php artisan optimize
$php artisan config:cache
```

and I update my composer using this command

```
$composer update
```

but nothing has changed.

Sorry for my terrible English.
Waiting your comments and Answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting your from to `{{ url('/') }}` using `POST` method that means it is submitting as a `POST` to `/` route and your `/` route is defined by  `GET`  method in your `web.php` that is why you are getting this error

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Route::get('/', 'StoriesController@index');
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I modified my code then, the error message has disappeared. But new problem has occurred. My posting form doesn't work. Is there any problems in my code?

Comment: @TakamasaYoshizawa are you getting any error after submitting?. Also pls share your updated code.

Comment: yes, there are no error messages but my post form doesn't work correctly. It couldn't post an image. I update my code. (web.php)

Comment: Can you please share `StoriesController@index` code

Comment: I add `index2.blade.php` on my question.

Comment: No, please share your controller's code where your are posting your image.

Comment: My controllers's code is already on my question. `app/Http/Controllers/StoriesController.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208746/discussion-between-sehdev-and-takamasa-yoshizawa).